# Is there a general formula for $ (x + y)^m$? where m is an nonnegative integer number , and x and y are non - commutative .

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

We know that if x and y are commutative, we get the following result
$$
(x+y)^m = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} x^k y^{m-k}
$$
for nonnegative integer number m. But is there a general formula for the above expression if x and y are non-commutative?

Comment: Of course there's a general formula as a sum of products of $x$ and $y$, but it would be of incredibly limited utility.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ real numbers? If so, they are commutative

Answer (score 6):

If multiplication between x and y is non-commutative and we assume distributivity applies, then you end up with the sum of each possible term of the form $a_1 a_2 a_3 ...a_m$, where $a_k$ is either $x$ or $y$ for each choice of $k$. Formally, this might look something like
$$
(x+y)^m = \sum_{a_k \in \{x,y\}} \prod_{k=1}^m a_k
$$
where the sum is taken over all possible choices of $a_k$.

Note that the sum contains $2^m$ terms, each having $m$ factors. Note also, that the sum of the binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=1}^m {m\choose k}=2^m$. This is not a coincidence. In the classical binomial theorem the binomial coefficients come up because there are $m\choose k$ ways to order $k$ $x$'s and $m-k$ $y$'s. When multiplication is commutative, we can group all of these terms together in a single term with coefficient $m \choose k$. Without commutativity we simply keep those terms separate.

Answer (score 5):

See jgd's answer.
For example,
$$
(x+y)^3 = xxx+xxy+xyx+yxx+xyy+yxy+yyx+yyy ,
$$
with no simplification available.
Generally, $(x+y)^m$ has $2^m$ terms.

Answer (score 4):

A non-commutative treatment is given by the so-called $q$-calculus. We consider the product $yx$ an *inversion* of $xy$ and describe the relation between these two products as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{yx=qxy}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We derive using (1)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x+y)^3}&=xxx+xxy+xyx+yxx+xyy+xyx+yyx+yyy\\
&=xxx+xxy+qxxy+q^2xxy+yxx+qxxy+q^2xyy+yyy\\
&=x^3+(1+q+q^2)x^2y+(1+q+q^2)xy^2+y^3\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=x^3+[3]x^2y+[3]xy^2+y^3}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
The exponent of $q$ gives the number of *mismatches*, the number of inversions needed to transform a word like $yxx$ to $xxy$. Here we use the notation
\begin{align*}
[n]:=1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
\end{align*}
and call it the *q-analogue* of $n$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{q\to 1}\,[n]=\lim_{q\to 1}\left(1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}\right)=n
\end{align*}
which makes this notation plausible. Generalising (2) gives
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x+y)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n {\begin{bmatrix} n\\k\end{bmatrix}}x^jy^{n-j}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we use the notation
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} n\\k\end{bmatrix}:=\frac{[n]!}{[k]![n-k]!}\qquad\textrm{where}\qquad [k]!=[k][k-1]\cdots[1]
\end{align*}

*Note:* In q-calculus there is another expression used as *q-analogue* of the binomial $(x+y)^n$, namely
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x+y)^n_q:=(x+y)(x+qy)\cdots \left(x+q^{n-1}y\right)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
which has more convenient properties than (3) especially with respect to *q-derivatives*. The following identity is called *Gauss's binomial formula*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x+y)^n_q=\sum_{j=0}^n{\begin{bmatrix} n\\k\end{bmatrix}}q^{\binom{j}{2}}y^{n-j}x^j}
\end{align*}
which is formula (5.5) in *[Quantum calculus](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-0071-7#about-this-book)* by Victor Kac.